# pip install: upgrade a library in /usr without sudo

Tags: python, unix, pip, sudo

`python-six` is installed in `/usr` and I need to upgrade it, but I don't have root privileges.

I know how to install a library without root privileges:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/.local" six
```

I know how to upgrade a library with root privileges:

```
pip install --upgrade six
```

But when I try to upgrade the library as so:

```
pip install --upgrade --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/.local" six
```

I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.7.3.tar.gz#md5=784c6e5541c3c4952de9c0a966a0a80b
  Running setup.py egg_info for package six

    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.2.0
    Uninstalling six:
Exception:
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/pyshared/six-1.2.0.egg-info'
```

So, how can I upgrade `six` without sudo?

Comment: You can install python in your home directory.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when I try to install any library to home dir using `pip install --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/.local" package` I get that the library is already installed. did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean you can install Python from source to any dir you specify then add path to bashrc and you can then install any package

Comment: @PadraicCunningham would be great if you could provide an answer with those instructions detailed out in the form of code!

Comment: I am on my phone now but this is a link to explain the options https://docs.python.org/2/install/. I will add a step by step later if you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this - I would recommend working inside a virtual environment:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Then you will have total control of your Modules without bugging the SysAdmin for sudo

HTH's Thanks //P

Disclaimer - involves more pip work ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm trying it out right now. I have limited local storage space, so is there a way to make sure that, when I `pip install` a library, it will only do so if the library is not already installed inside `/usr`? and make sure that, when I `pip install --upgrade` a library, it will only do so if there is not the latest version of the library installed inside `usr`?

Comment: Yes that is possible you can either use the --system-site-packages flag when creating the virtual env so virtualenv --system-site-packages foo then source foo/bin/activate - or you can use the --no-site-packages argument and ln -s the libraries you want into place :-)